# Integration using euler's formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the following integral: $$\int\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx.$$ I tried using Euler's formula and put $xt+1=\sqrt{1+x-x^2}$ and after to do integration in parts but that goes nowhere. Is there anotehr method to solve it?

Comment: Please let me know if I changed your question in the edit.

Comment: no.thats the question. thanks.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Are you still having trouble with this integral?

Comment: yes.I think that there was a mistake in the solution of @Sami (the t is inside the root) so instead of the $$t=sin\theta$$, I did $$t=\frac{(sin\theta-3)^2}{5}$$ and then the regular $$r=tg0.5\theta$$. then I got expression with $$tg0.5 \theta$$ which can be developed to the identity $$\frac{1-cosx}{sinx}$$. since we know sinx we just need cos. I draw a triangle which its anglea are $$\theta , 90, 90-\theta$$ and got that $$cos\theta=\sqrt{-8-5t-6\sqrt{5t}}$$ . Solving it a bit and I got that the answer is $$\frac{4(x+1)}{\sqrt{5}[-2x-1-\sqrt{-(2x+1)(2x+3)}]}+c$$.Maple claims i'm wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** We proceed by successive variable change:
$$I=\int\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\int\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{1-(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{5}})^2}}$$
with $t=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{5}}$ we find
$$I=2\int\frac{dt}{(\sqrt{5}t+3)\sqrt{1-t^2}}.$$
Now by $t=\sin(\theta)$ we have
$$I=2\int\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{5}\sin\theta+3}$$
Finally, we pose $s=\tan(\theta/2)$  to find the desired result.

Comment: excuse me but shouldn't it be $\sqrt 5t$ instead of $\sqrt(5t)$?

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane I think you meant to set $t=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt 5}$ (without the square).

Comment: Thanks,now expression improved... Even though, in the last level (after possing $$s=tg(0.5\theta)$$, I'm stuck with $$\int \frac{2}{3s^2+2\sqrt{5}s+3}ds$$. How can I continue from there?

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Try completing the square in the denominator to get something that looks like $1+(\varphi (s))^2$, where $\varphi$ is a linear function. Then antiderivate using $\arctan$.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner [Here](http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/complete_sq/) is an example.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I'll correct the typo

Answer (score 0):

I have tried few steps but i m not sure thats ok or not.

$$\int\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx.$$

let $1+x = t$

hence $dx = dt$

$$\int\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx. = \int\frac{1}{t\sqrt{t-(t-1)^2}}dt = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^3-(t^2)(t-1)^2}}dt$$

Comment: I also tried that and if I didn't have mistake letting 1+x=t won't solving it hence you get in the root polynom you can't simplfy/ integrate its 1/root. I also tried with this integration in parts (f'=1 and g=1/sqrt) but it didn't help.thanks anyway...